# Building Java file at runtime & running JUnit test on that class file

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I am trying to build a Dynamic web project where user can practice Java code.

I got success on  writing the `code` written by user in a `.java` file, `compile` the code & get `error messages` using `Java Compile API`.

Now, I need to run `JUnit 1.4 Compatible` test on that `code`.

I researched for it, and found something like `parameterized junit testing`. But my view on how should it be done isn't still clear.

**UPDATE**

This (http://codingbat.com/prob/p171896) is the exact thing what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: The first publicly-available version of JUnit was 3.7. Maybe you mean "JUnit4 Compatible", which was a big version change over the previous JUnit3, or "JUnit for Java 1.4", which [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071894/junit-for-java-1-4) defines nicely?

Comment: @JeffBowman thanx for noticing the question. Its actually "JUnit for Java 1.4". I know the JUnit testing, and had been using it for my projects. But in this project. I need to test the class file at runtime, which is written by the user. There comes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with the following steps:

1. Compile the JUnit TestClass and the ClassToTest

   ```
   JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
   int compilerResult = compiler.run(null, null, null,"/path/to/TestClass.java", "/path/to/ClassToTest.java");
   System.out.println("Compiler result code: " + compilerResult);
   ```
2. Load the compiled classes into the classloader

   ```
   File dir = new File("/path/to/class/files/");
   URL url = dir.toURI().toURL();
   URL[] urls = {url};
   ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
   ```
3. Run the tests (make sure that you add junit as a dependency of your project)

   ```
   Class<?> junitTest = Class.forName("TestClass", true, classLoader);
   Result result = junit.run(junitTest);
   ```

Edit: If you're not needing the JUnit tests to be dynamic you can skip the compilation of those tests and add them here: `junit.run(JunitTest.class)`